# Protect Sheet from inserting rows only in a specific range

Tags: vba, excel, protected

I am trying to find a way to allow the user to insert rows but only in a specific range when the sheet is protected. For example, I don't want the user to be able to insert a row between the rows "1" and "2" (because it will make my macros do funny things), but I want him to be able to insert a row everywhere else.

The following code allows the user to insert rows everywhere in the sheet, but that is not exactly what I want:

```
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="qwerty", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
```

Can somebody help me with this issue ?

Comment: a simple way would be something like a "very hidden sheet"... having in `A1` the formula `=A2`. Then simply check for it and if the formula isn't `=A2` then simply `Application.Undo` :P

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to prevent the user from inserting rows only in specific ranges, you could lock those cells and prevent selection of locked cells so the user doesn't select cells in the top two rows which might prevent them from accidentally doing it?

You could also lock row insertion and set `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` and deal with any row insertion through a macro, cancelling the procedure if they're trying to insert a row in the wrong place.

Is it a necessity that the users can insert rows throughout the worksheet?

Comment: We can achieve this by Worksheets SelectionChange  Event.

Comment: It's more than a bit janky though

Comment: Yes it is :) but as he has only asked how to do this so i put the code .

Comment: Yes, it is a database so it is a necessity. I think that Shrikant found a solution to my problem, thank you very much for your help !

Comment: If you need a database and have Microsoft Office, I'd recommend you port it to Access. You can write an excel workbook to communicate with it etc. and in general it'll be a lot easier down the line if you're using database-specific software, even if it's a hassle to set up now. There's no good way to have several users able to edit a workbook at the same time, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code on Worksheet Selection Change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 Or Target.Row = 2 Then
        'MsgBox "Check"
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="qwerty", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="qwerty"
    End If
End Sub
```